# add case sensitive to barcode field in Odoo

Tags: barcode, case-sensitive, case-insensitive, odoo-15

I'm Odoo 15 , I realized that Odoo product barcode field is case sensitive. So, however barcodes are unique but it could be duplicated.
Odoo barcode field accept the following case
Product1 barcode: A123
Product2 barcode: a123

I want to prevent that from happening , I need to make barcode unique even over the letter case.
from developer mode> Edit View: Form
this is the barcode field code that I found in the product.template.product.form

```
<field name="barcode" attrs="{'invisible': [('product_variant_count', '&gt;', 1)]}"/>
```

What attributes I can add to make the field not sensitive to the case of the letter ?

thank you